# Rails, Cequel - Don't know how to cast to a UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cequel

I'm following this tutorial (https://medium.com/@olance/rails-4-user-authentication-with-cequel-and-devise-86e1c9ccbcd0), but I'm having problems with the login. When I receive the following error:

---

### ArgumentError in HomeController#index

Don't know how to cast {"n"=>242893962554067921677178635377202198460} to a UUID

Extracted source (around line #423):

```
      Cql::Uuid.new(value)
    else
      fail ArgumentError,
           "Don't know how to cast #{value.inspect} to a UUID" # Line 423
    end
  end
```

---

The model used by devise is:

```
class User
  include Cequel::Record

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable

  key :id, :uuid, auto => true
  column :username, :varchar, :index => true
  column :name, :varchar
  column :lastname, :varchar
  column :email, :varchar, :index => true
  column :encrypted_password, :varchar
  timestamps
end
```

If I change the key to a varchar it works, but I wan't to use a UUID, so that the user can change the email or its username.

How can it be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in source of method `uuid` you will see [here](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/blob/master/lib/cequel/uuids.rb):

```
def uuid(value = nil)
  if value.nil?
    timeuuid_generator.now
  elsif value.is_a?(Time)
    timeuuid_generator.at(value)
  elsif value.is_a?(DateTime)
    timeuuid_generator.at(Time.at(value.to_f))
  else
    Type::Timeuuid.instance.cast(value)
  end
end
```

It means that at it suppose values like `nil`, `Time`, `DateTime`. In none of them it will use method `cast` of Type::Timeuuid which is located [somewhere here](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/blob/master/lib/cequel/type.rb)

Any of `cast` method definitions seems to be not awaiting to receivce a `hash`

As a workaround you could try something like `Cql::Uuid.new(value['n'])`
But you should check out why you get a hash there, and what should it really be

Comment: It seems that I'm doing something wrong of cequel+devise don't like the uuid as a user key. With a varchar works right.